# Python code breaks when attemting to download larger zipped csv file, works fine on smaller file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests, unzip

while working with small zipfiles(about 8MB) containg 25MB of CSV files the below code works exactly as it should. As soon as I attempt to download larger files (45MB zip file containing a 180MB csv) the code breaks and I get the following error message:

```
(venv) ufulu@ufulu awr % python get_awr_ranking_data.py
https://api.awrcloud.com/v2/get.php?action=get_topsites&token=REDACTED&project=REDACTED Client+%5Bw%5D&fileName=2017-01-04-2019-10-09
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_awr_ranking_data.py", line 101, in <module>
    getRankingData(project['name'])
  File "get_awr_ranking_data.py", line 67, in getRankingData
    processRankingdata(rankDateData['details'])
  File "get_awr_ranking_data.py", line 79, in processRankingdata
    domain.append(row.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0])
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My goal is to download data for 170 projects and save the data to sqlite DB.

Please bear with me me as I am a novice in the field of programming and python. I would greatly appreciate any help to fixing the code below as well as any other sugestions and improvements to making the code more robust and pythonic.

Thanks in advance

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# SQL Alchemy setup

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///rankingdata.sqlite', echo=False)



# Excerpt from the initial API Call

data = {'projects': [{'name': 'Client1',
   'id': '168',
   'frequency': 'daily',
   'depth': '5',
   'kwcount': '80',
   'last_updated': '2019-10-01',
   'keywordstamp': 1569941983},
                     {
                         "depth": "5",
                         "frequency": "ondemand",
                         "id": "194",
                         "kwcount": "10",
                         "last_updated": "2019-09-30",
                         "name": "Client2",
                         "timestamp": 1570610327
                     },

                     {
                         "depth": "5",
                         "frequency": "ondemand",
                         "id": "196",
                         "kwcount": "100",
                         "last_updated": "2019-09-30",
                         "name": "Client3",
                         "timestamp": 1570610331
                     }  
                     ]}

#setup
api_url = 'https://api.awrcloud.com/v2/get.php?action='
urls = [] # processed URLs
urlbacklog = [] # URLs that didn't return a downloadable File

# API Call to recieve URL containing downloadable zip and csv
def getRankingData(project):
    action = 'get_dates'
    response = requests.get(''.join([api_url, action]),
                            params=dict(token=dotenv_values()['AWR_API'],
                                        project=project))
    response = response.json()
    action2 = 'topsites_export'
    rankDateData = requests.get(''.join([api_url, action2]),
                            params=dict(token=dotenv_values()['AWR_API'],
                                        project=project, startDate=response['details']['dates'][0]['date'], stopDate=response['details']['dates'][-1]['date'] ))

    rankDateData = rankDateData.json()
    print(rankDateData['details'])
    urls.append(rankDateData['details'])
    processRankingdata(rankDateData['details'])

# API Call to download and unzip csv data and process it in pandas
def processRankingdata(url):
    content = requests.get(url)
    # {"response_code":25,"message":"Export in progress. Please come back later"}
    if "response_code" not in content:
        f = ZipFile(BytesIO(content.content))
        #print(f.namelist()) to get all filenames in Zip
        with f.open(f.namelist()[0], 'r') as g: rankingdatadf = pd.read_csv(g)
        rankingdatadf = rankingdatadf[rankingdatadf['Search Engine'].str.contains("Google")]
        domain = []
        for row in rankingdatadf['URL']:
            domain.append(row.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0])
        rankingdatadf['Domain'] = domain
        rankingdatadf['Domain'] = rankingdatadf['Domain'].str.replace('www.', '')
        rankingdatadf = rankingdatadf.drop(columns=['Title', 'Meta description', 'Snippet', 'Page'])
        print(rankingdatadf['Search Engine'][0])
        writeData(rankingdatadf)
    else:
        urlbacklog.append(url)
        pass
# Finally write the data to database
def writeData(rankingdatadf):
    table_name_from_file = project['name']
    check = engine.has_table(table_name_from_file)
    print(check)  # boolean
    if check == False:
        rankingdatadf.to_sql(table_name_from_file, con=engine)
        print(project['name'] + ' ...Done')
    else:
        print(project['name'] + ' ... already in DB')


for project in data['projects']:
    getRankingData(project['name'])
```

Comment: this looks prommissing! The exception thrown is: `nan` how do I mitigate this?

Comment: thank you so much for this wonderful hint! after adding `rankingdatadf = rankingdatadf.fillna(0) ` my code works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the split call on a float and not necessarily the download. Try changing line 79

from

```py
domain.append(row.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0])
```

to

```py
domain.append(str(str(str(row).split("//")[-1]).split("/")[0]).split('?')[0])
```

It looks like you're trying to parse the network location portion of the URL here, you can also use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to make this easier instead of chaining all the splits:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
...
for row in rankingdatadf['URL']:
   domain.append(urlparse(row).netloc)
```

---

I think a malformed URL is causing you issues, try (to diagnose issue):

try :

```py
for row in rankingdatadf['URL']:
   try:
       domain.append(urlparse(row).netloc)
   catch Exception:
       exit(row)
```

---

Looks like you figured it out above, you have a database entry with a NULL value for the URL field. Not sure what your fidelity requirements for this data set are but might want to enforce database rules for URL field, or use pandas to drop rows where URL is NaN.

```py
rankingdatadf = rankingdatadf.dropna(subset=['URL'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. After chaning to urlparse I get the following error: 
`domain.append(urlparse(row).netloc)
"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 367, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 107, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: I think a malformed URL is causing issues.

try :
```python
for row in rankingdatadf['URL']:
   try:
       domain.append(urlparse(row).netloc)
   catch Exception:
       exit(row)
```

To observer which url is causing issues.